# GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions Never returns results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, subscription

Using the explorer in various browsers, as the tenant global admin the query runs for long time and returns no subscriptions.
I know for a fact that we have one for each of many site collections.

Is there another way to get the web-hooks subscriptions and extend the expirationDateTime?
All my subscriptions are close to their expirationDateTime.

Answer (score 3):

By default, apps can only read subscriptions that they themselves created. So if you're using Graph Explorer, it hasn't created any subscriptions, so you get 0 results. Not sure why it's running for a long time though.

If you're an admin, then you can consent to the `Subscriptions.Read.All` permission so you can list them all. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/subscription-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#advanced-scenarios). To do this in Graph Explorer, click the gear icon next to your username and photo on the left side, and choose **Select permissions**. Select the `Subscriptions.Read.All` permission and click **Consent**.

[image]

I don't believe this will allow you to extend the expiration though, since the permission is `Read`, not `ReadWrite`. My guess is only the app that created the subscription can extend it.

Comment: Thanks. I have Subscriptions.Read.All v and Consented but I get "value": [] . I know I have a few. If they are all expired, would I get there value? Is there a way to run the explorer as the application?

Comment: Where can I give an app permissions on Subscriptions? I looked at Grag and SharePoint in Azure but did not find it